# Python Regex or Filename Function

Tags: python, regex, file, text

Question about rename file name in folder. My file name looks like this:

```
EPG CRO 24 Kitchen 09.2013.xsl
```

With name space between, and I used code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Remove whitespace from files where EPG named with space " " replace with "_"
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.find("2013|09 ") > 0:
        newfilename = filename.replace(" ","_")
        os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

With this code I removed white space, but how can I remove date, from file name so it can look like this: `EPG_CRO_24_Kitche.xsl`. Can you give me some solution about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regex

As utdemir was eluding to, regular expressions can really help in situations like these. If you have never been exposed to them, it can be confusing at first. Checkout https://www.debuggex.com/r/4RR6ZVrLC_nKYs8g for a useful tool that helps you construct regular expressions.

### Solution

An updated solution would be:

```
import re

def rename_file(filename):
  if filename.startswith('EPG') and ' ' in filename:
    # \s+       means 1 or more whitespace characters                                   
    # [0-9]{2}  means exactly 2 characters of 0 through 9                               
    # \.        means find a '.' character                                              
    # [0-9]{4}  means exactly 4 characters of 0 through 9                               
    newfilename = re.sub("\s+[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}", '', filename)
    newfilename = newfilename.replace(" ","_")
    os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

### Side Note

```
# Remove whitespace from files where EPG named with space " " replace with "_"
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.find("2013|09 ") > 0:
        newfilename = filename.replace(" ","_")
        os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

Unless I'm mistaken, the from the comment you made above, `filename.find("2013|09 ") > 0` won't work.

Given the following:

```
In [76]: filename = "EPG CRO 24 Kitchen 09.2013.xsl"
In [77]: filename.find("2013|09 ")
Out[77]: -1
```

And your described comment, you might want something more like:

```
In [80]: if filename.startswith('EPG') and ' ' in filename:
   ....:     print('process this')
   ....:     
process this
```

Comment: When I run code above I got only on some files, but other's stay same.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that helped. Can you provide the output of os.listdir('.') so I can what the file names are?

Answer (score 1):

If all file names have the same format: `NAME_20XX_XX.xsl`, then you can use python's list `slicing` instead of `regex`:

```
name.replace(' ','_')[:-12] + '.xsl'
```

Answer (score 1):

If dates are always formatted same;

```
>>> s = "EPG CRO 24 Kitchen 09.2013.xsl"
>>> re.sub("\s+\d{2}\.\d{4}\..{3}$", "", s)
'EPG CRO 24 Kitchen'
```

Comment: Date is for moths so next month will be like  EPG CRO 24 Kitchen 10.2013.xsl

Comment: This regex matches:

* One or more whitespace
* Followed by two digits, a dot, four digits,
* Followed by a dot and three characters(extension)
* And end of string.

Answer (score 1):

How about little slicing:

```
newfilename = input1[:input1.rfind(" ")].replace(" ","_")+input1[input1.rfind("."):]
```